# yet another Scala abstract type and a path-dependent situation

Tags: scala, types

I'm playing around with Scala. I have somethis like this:

```
trait Test {
  type SweetType

  def methodA(l: String, esc: Boolean): SweetType
  def methodB(a: SweetType): String
}

class MyTest extends Test {

  override type SweetType = (String, Boolean)

  override def methodA(l: String, esc: Boolean): (String, Boolean) = ???

  override def methodB(a: (String, Boolean)): String = ???
}

object Test {
  def apply(): Test = new MyTest()
}
```

MyTest is a concrete implementation of Test, i would like to keep at *trait* level without a defintion *SweetType*, is just design information.

```
trait SomethingElse {    
  val test:Test
  def methodA(a:test.SweetType):String
}
```

The concrete implementation of this trait will use what Test provides.

```
class MySomethingElse extends SomethingElse {
  val test = Test()

  override def methodA(a:test.SweetType):String = test.methodB(a) + "Cuanak"

}
```

Here is my question, this is scala-legal, but is done right? or i should use a opaque trait or somethis like that?
I just want to make referece to any concrete implementation of the abstract type defined in Test "SweetType"

**edit** i forgot a reference in the trait Test

## UPDATE!

For my case works best using the "cake pattern"

```
trait TestComponent {

  val test:Test

  trait Test {
    type SweetType

    def methodA(l: String, esc: Boolean): SweetType

    def methodB(a: SweetType): String
  }

  class MyTest extends Test {

    override type SweetType = (String, Boolean)

    override def methodA(l: String, esc: Boolean): (String, Boolean) = ???

    override def methodB(a: (String, Boolean)): String = ???
  }

}


trait SomethingElseComponent {
  this :TestComponent =>

  trait SomethingElse {

    def methodA(a:Test#SweetType):String
  }


  class MySomethingElse extends SomethingElse {

    override def methodA(a:Test#SweetType):String = test.methodB(a) + "Cuanak"

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks well-designed to me. This is a common pattern: a `trait` with both abstract and concrete members, an object that provides specifics for the abstract members. And, as you observed, you can put a `trait` abstract `val` in another `trait` to aggregate all the abstract members.

This is analogous in math to making abstract structures that relate to other abstract structures:

```
trait Ring {
  type E
  def add(x: E, y: E): E
  def mul(x: E, y: E): E
  def minus(x: E): E
  val zero: E
  val one: E
}

trait Module {
  val ring: Ring
  import ring._

  type V

  def add(x: V, y: V): V
  def mul(x: E, y: V): V
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answering, do you think that in the trait _SomethingElse_ is right to make explicity that you must have a **val test:Test** or there's another way to express _SomethingElse_ without that?

Comment: Another way would be `trait SomethingElse extends Test` or `trait SomethingElse { this: Test => .... }`. This would be problematic for your `Test.apply()` since it is not possible to mix in a trait at runtime. Personally I prefer `val test: Test`.